# How to update data in an AnimatedList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

How do you update data (add, remove rows) in an AnimatedList in Flutter? I can do it in a ListView by just updating the backing data and calling `setState`. For example,

```
setState(() {
  _data.insert(2, 'pig');
});
```

It seems more complicated in an AnimatedList, though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The various ways to update the AnimatedList are demonstrated below. The process includes two main steps every time:

1. Update the data set
2. Notify the AnimatedList's global key about the change

## Insert single item

Add "Pig" at index `2`.

[image]

```
String item = "Pig";
int insertIndex = 2;
_data.insert(insertIndex, item);
_listKey.currentState.insertItem(insertIndex);
```

## Insert multiple items

Insert three animals at index 2.

[image]

```
final items = ['Pig', 'Chichen', 'Dog'];
int insertIndex = 2;
_data.insertAll(insertIndex, items);
// This is a bit of a hack because currentState doesn't have
// an insertAll() method.
for (int offset = 0; offset < items.length; offset++) {
  _listKey.currentState.insertItem(insertIndex + offset);
}
```

## Remove single item

Remove "Pig" from the list.

[image]

```
int removeIndex = 2;
String removedItem = _data.removeAt(removeIndex);
// This builder is just so that the animation has something
// to work with before it disappears from view since the original
// has already been deleted.
AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
  // A method to build the Card widget.
  return _buildItem(removedItem, animation);
};
_listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
```

## Remove multiple items

Remove "Camel" and "Sheep" from the list.

[image]

```
int removeIndex = 2;
int count = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  String removedItem = _data.removeAt(removeIndex);
  AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
    return _buildItem(removedItem, animation);
  };
  _listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
}
```

## Supplemental code

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Update AnimatedList data')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyWidgetState createState() {
    return new BodyWidgetState();
  }
}

class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {

  // the GlobalKey is needed to animate the list
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  // backing data
  List<String> _data = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: AnimatedList(
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: _data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
              return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
            },
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            'Insert single item',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _onButtonPress();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onButtonPress() {
    // replace this with method choice below
    _insertSingleItem();
  }

  void _insertSingleItem() {
    String item = "Pig";
    int insertIndex = 2;
    _data.insert(insertIndex, item);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(insertIndex);
  }

  void _insertMultipleItems() {
    final items = ['Pig', 'Chichen', 'Dog'];
    int insertIndex = 2;
    _data.insertAll(insertIndex, items);
    // This is a bit of a hack because currentState doesn't have
    // an insertAll() method.
    for (int offset = 0; offset < items.length; offset++) {
      _listKey.currentState.insertItem(insertIndex + offset);
    }
  }

  void _removeSingleItems() {
    int removeIndex = 2;
    String removedItem = _data.removeAt(removeIndex);
    // This builder is just so that the animation has something
    // to work with before it disappears from view since the original
    // has already been deleted.
    AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
      // A method to build the Card widget.
      return _buildItem(removedItem, animation);
    };
    _listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
  }

  void _removeMultipleItems() {
    int removeIndex = 2;
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      String removedItem = _data.removeAt(removeIndex);
      AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
        return _buildItem(removedItem, animation);
      };
      _listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**

- If your list items include any stateful widgets then you will need to give them keys so that the system can keep track of them.
- Although I wrote this answer before I wrote the Medium article, I am now maintaining [my answer on Medium](https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-animatedlist-in-flutter-9dbfb136e515). Check there for the latest updates.

Comment: Is it possible to update the existing data at an index, rather than removing and adding it again? For instance, I have a text at an index and I want to change the text value. How do I do it?

Comment: @Rakesh You can use `setState` and just update the data list. I expanded my answer [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-animatedlist-in-flutter-9dbfb136e515) to describe that.

Comment: There is now _listKey.currentState.insertAllItems(index,length) method you can use instead of the hacky for loop.

`_listKey.currentState.insertAllItems(0,items.length);`